# Graphing probability distribution using R and checking other solutions

Tags: r, probability, distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to solve questions in my statistics book. There is a question a want you check me and help for the  part iv :

> Consider a population of 100 computer, 45 of whom are broken, and the rest are nonbroken.
>
> i) If you select 10 computer at random but with replacement, find the probability that 4 are
> broken.
>
> ii) Now assume you select ten people without replacement, find the same probability.
>
> iii) What is the probability distribution that gives probabilities in
> i) and what is it in ii)
>
> iv) Using cumulative probability distribution(s) and graph(s) try to show that probabilities >converge between the cases with replacement and without the replacement as the population size
> increases relative to size of selection, i.e. sample size.

My answers:

iv-) I cannot do this part

I stuck in part iv , i  am beginner in R language so i could not write codes for part iv.Can you help me for it , i need to show it using cumulative probability distribution(s) and graph(s) in R.Moreover , are i ,ii,iii correct ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen i wrote my answers for i,ii,iii. what should i do ?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen i need r code for part iv

Comment: R code: (i) `dbinom(4, 10, .45)` returns $0.2383666,$ as does `choose(10,4)*.45^4*.55^6`, so that part is correct. (ii) `dhyper(4, 45,55, 10)` returns $0.2495228$ as does
`choose(45,4)*choose(55,6)/choose(100,10)` so your formula is correct, but the distribution is hypergeometric, not binomial, in this part. // Part (iv) is not clearly stated. Selecting only 10 observations will not give much of a clue as to convergence. What is the exact statement of (iv)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Graphical comment:**

For whatever help it may provide, the
CDFs of the binomial distribution in (i) and the
hypergeometric distribution in (ii) are almost the
same, because only 10 of 100 people have been
sampled.

A plot of the two CDFs from R is shown below.
(The vertical resolution of such a graph is
about two decimal places.)

[image]

R code for the figure (using base R graphics).

```
x = 0:10
Bino.CDF = pbinom(x, 10, .45)
Hypr.CDF = phyper(x, 45,55, 10)
hdr = "Binomial (solid blue) and Hypergeometric (dotted) CDFs"
plot(x, Bino.CDF, type="s", col="blue", ylab="CDF", main=hdr)
 points(x, Bino.CDF, pch=20, col="blue")
lines(x, Hypr.CDF, type="s", lwd=3, lty="dotted", col="brown")
 points(x, Hypr.CDF, col="brown")
```